# Can't SSH into EC2 from my mac but can from other devices

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect into an EC2 instance (i am using a mac) which has a Security Group allowing all inbound traffic over ssh (port 22) but i'm unable to access. I'm having a little delay before getting an *Operation timed out*.

I already tried it over other devices such a raspberry pi and another macbook and the connection was successful.
I got access to the raspberry pi over ssh and tried the connection to my EC2 from the terminal; thought my ssh client or the port status could be the issue but after doing this i'm not really sure if this is the case.

This is the message i get when trying to connect:

> ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out

One thing I noticed is that I used a different .pem file which is supposed to not work for that instance and the error was the same, it looks like my Mac cannot reach it.

Things already verified:

- Security Group allowing traffic over port 22.
- Instance rebooted/recreated.
- DNS and Public IP address changed after instance reboot.
- SSH connection successful over other devices.
- SSH connection to other devices from this mac successful.
- Firewall turned off.
- DNS flushed.
- Ping performed with success.

Any help is really appreciated it.

**-- UPDATE --**

This issue rose in my work machine. Got a different laptop due to other issues and problem fixed, looks like it might have been something related to ports or some sort of configuration. Thought it was a problem with AWS but now it's working fine. Sadly I couldn't debug enough to know what the exact issue was. Thanks to everyone who helped out!

Comment: Were all these attempts from the same network? Sometimes, corporate networks block outbound SSH connections. If it works from other devices and the security group is open for all IP addresses, then the problem is with the Mac (and maybe its network), not AWS. If there is a delay before receiving that error, it suggests that the Mac is unable to reach the EC2 instance, as opposed to being denied access.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried it from 2 different networks, one at work and home, from both I was able to ssh before.

Regarding the delay, it is happening and as you say i don't think access is being denied. I was able to ping my instance successfully.

Comment: Ping is rarely a good test, since it requires specific ports to be open in a Security Group. It typically won't work for EC2 instances. I would suggest launching a new Amazon Linux instance and see whether you can SSH into it, to try and figure out what is happening.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Can't figure out what's going on after launching another AMI and failing to ssh again, i even launched it in another AZ. Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein One thing I noticed is that I used a different .pem file which is supposed to not work for that instance and the error was the same, it looks like my Mac cannot reach it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can remote by other devices and this issue is only still happening on your MAC. Try this on your MAC and try to remote again:

> Flush your DNS

I don't know which Mac OS you are using so I put the link here: (https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214981288-Flushing-your-DNS-cache-in-Mac-OS-X-and-Linux)

If still cannot, you can try to open some protocol ports on that instances like:

> ICMP, Echo Reply, ...

then try to reach by that protocol commands:

> Ping, telnet, ...

If the result is cannot too, so it must be that your MAC cannot even reach to that instance network, then try to ensure that your MAC can reach the instance's network first.

Comment: Flushed my DNS, sill unable to ssh. I was able to ping the instance though.

Comment: @GustavoMungarro Hmm, then I thought I should be the Firewall, do you ensure that your MAC's ssh client works with others machine? Have you tried to remote into other machines yet, except that instance?

Comment: Firewall is off and I've made an ssh connection successfully with other devices (Raspberry Pi), from which I ssh into the instance with no problem at all.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that I used a different .pem file which is supposed to not work for that instance and the error was the same, it looks like my Mac cannot reach it.